# 64 bit code generated by GCC is 3 times slower than 32 bit

Tags: c, performance, gcc, 64-bit

I've noticed that my code runs on 64 bit Linux much slower than on 32 bit Linux or 64 bit Window or 64 bit Mac. This is minimal test case.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char UINT8;

void
stretch(UINT8 * lineOut, UINT8 * lineIn, int xsize, float *kk)
{
    int xx, x;

    for (xx = 0; xx < xsize; xx++) {
        float ss = 0.0;
        for (x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
            ss += lineIn[x] * kk[x];
        }
        lineOut[xx] = (UINT8) ss;
    }
}

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int i;
    int xsize = 2048;

    UINT8 *lineIn = calloc(xsize, sizeof(UINT8));
    UINT8 *lineOut = calloc(xsize, sizeof(UINT8));
    float *kk = calloc(xsize, sizeof(float));

    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        stretch(lineOut, lineIn, xsize, kk);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And there is how it runs:

```
$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
$ cc -O2 -Wall -m64 ./tt.c -o ./tt && time ./tt
user  14.166s
$ cc -O2 -Wall -m32 ./tt.c -o ./tt && time ./tt
user  5.018s
```

As you can see, 32 bit version runs almost 3 times faster (I've tested both on 32bit and 64bit Ubuntu, result the same). And even more strange what performance depends on C standard:

```
$ cc -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -m32 ./tt.c -o ./tt && time ./tt
user  15.825s
$ cc -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -m32 ./tt.c -o ./tt && time ./tt
user  5.090s
```

How can it be? How can I workaround this to speed up 64 bit version generated by GCC.

**Update 1**

I've compared assembler produced by fast 32 bit (default and gnu99) and slow (c99) and found following:

```
.L5:
  movzbl    (%ebx,%eax), %edx   # MEM[base: lineIn_10(D), index: _72, offset: 0B], D.1543
  movl  %edx, (%esp)    # D.1543,
  fildl (%esp)  #
  fmuls (%esi,%eax,4)   # MEM[base: kk_18(D), index: _72, step: 4, offset: 0B]
  addl  $1, %eax    #, x
  cmpl  %ecx, %eax  # xsize, x
  faddp %st, %st(1) #,
  fstps 12(%esp)    #
  flds  12(%esp)    #
  jne   .L5 #,
```

There is no `fstps` and `flds` commands in fast case. So GCC stores and loads value from memory on each step. I've tried `register float` type, but this doesn't help.

**Update 2**

I've tested on gcc-4.9 and looks like it generates optimal code for 64 bit. And `-ffast-math` (suggested by @jch) fixes `-m32 -std=c99` for both GCC versions. I'm still looking for solution for 64 bit on gcc-4.8, because it is more common version for now that 4.9.

Comment: A factor of 3 hints at [auto-vectorization](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) failing.  Have a look at the -S assembly listing.

Comment: @HansPassant No, "Vectorization is enabled by the flag -ftree-vectorize and by default at -O3".

Comment: when running the program without gcc optimization, i got ~ execution time (user:0m14.349s(x86) VS 0m14.723s (x86_64)). GCC optimization failing?!

Comment: Not relevant to the problem, but in the interest of being informational: you can't define a function called `stretch()`, all public function names starting with `str` are reserved.

Comment: @unwind All characters appearing in this work are fictitious. Any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.

Comment: Have you checked that the version of libc6, as compiled for a 64 bit architecture, is being used for the 64bit versions of the compile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a partial dependency stall in the code generated by older versions of GCC.

```
movzbl (%rsi,%rax), %r8d
cvtsi2ss %r8d, %xmm0  ;; all upper bits in %xmm0 are false dependency
```

The dependency can be broken by `xorps`.

```cpp
#ifdef __SSE__
float __attribute__((always_inline)) i2f(int v) {
    float x;
    __asm__("xorps %0, %0; cvtsi2ss %1, %0" : "=x"(x) : "r"(v) );
    return x;
}
#else
float __attribute__((always_inline)) i2f(int v) { return (float) v; }
#endif

void stretch(UINT8* lineOut, UINT8* lineIn, int xsize, float *kk)
{
    int xx, x;

    for (xx = 0; xx < xsize; xx++) {
        float ss = 0.0;
        for (x = 0; x < xsize; x++) {
            ss += i2f(lineIn[x]) * kk[x];
        }
        lineOut[xx] = (UINT8) ss;
    }
}
```

Results

```
$ cc -O2 -Wall -m64 ./test.c -o ./test64 && time ./test64
./test64  4.07s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 4.070 total
$ cc -O2 -Wall -m32 ./test.c -o ./test32 && time ./test32
./test32  3.94s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.938 total
```

Comment: Wow, this works in my project, not only in test case. Only question is: how is this code cross-platform? Can `always_inline` break any compillers? Is all x86 64 bit target CPUs has `__SSE__` flag during compilation? Also I've noticed that `i2f` should be `static`.

Comment: @homm well, I guess if you guard it with right ifdefs (which I unfortunately can't tell you from the top of my head) it will be crossplatform :) I expect this already to build just fine on Mac/Linux with GCC and clang (even though clang does not really need this hack, it breaks dependency by itself). You will need to change `__attribute__` in `#else`-branch to `__forceinline` for MSVC but otherwise it should still work because MSVC does *not* define `__SSE__`.

Comment: If I were to include this code into my project I'd probably write it like this `#if (GCC_VERSION < 40900) && defined(__SSE__)`

Comment: Note that on systems that have an older gcc, there may also be an assembler that doesn't know about these instructions. I got `libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:40: Error: operand type mismatch for 'xorps' `         
`libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:40: Error: operand type mismatch for 'cvtsi2ss'       
` for code in the py-Pillow package that apparently picked up this trick.

Comment: the original code contained mistake, which caused the error you have seen @Rhialto, instead of `=X` it should have said `=x`. wrong register contraint.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I tried: I declared ss as **volatile**. This prevented the compiler from doing optimizations on it. I got similar times for both 32 and 64 bit versions.

64bit was slightly slower but this is normal because 64bit code is larger and the uCode cache has a finite size. So in general 64bit should be very slightly slower than 32 (<3-4%).

Getting back to the problem, I think that in 32bit mode the compiler makes more aggressive optimizations on ss.

**Update 1:**

Looking at the 64bit code, it generates a CVTTSS2SI instruction, paired with a CVTSI2SS instruction for float to integer conversion. This has a higher latency. The 32bit code just uses a FMULS instruction, operating directly on floats. Need to look for a compiler option to prevent these conversions.

Comment: I can't declare it as `int`, I need `float` there.

Answer (score 2):

In 32 bit mode, the compiler is making extra efforts to preserve strict IEEE 754 floating point semantics.  You can avoid this by compiling with `-ffast-math`:

```
$ gcc -m32 -O2 -std=c99 test.c && time ./a.out 

real    0m13.869s
user    0m13.884s
sys     0m0.000s
$ gcc -m32 -O2 -std=c99 -ffast-math test.c && time ./a.out 

real    0m4.477s
user    0m4.480s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I cannot reproduce your results in 64-bit mode, but I'm pretty confident that `-ffast-math` will solve your issues.  More generally, unless you really need reproducible IEEE 754 rounding behaviour, `-ffast-math` is what you want.

Comment: I suppose you're on gcc-4.9, looks like it generates fast code for 64 bit, but still slow for `-std=c99` without `-ffast-math`. On gcc-4.8 fast math doesn't help for `-m64`. But your answer is still most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I can reproduce your results with gcc-4.8, and indeed, neither `-ffast-math` nor `-march=corei7` solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case for restrict. The three arrays can't overlap, can they?